# Creating custom client node

Tags: go-ethereum

In a hypothetical situation is it possible to write a client node that mines only my transaction and save transaction fees? I know clients like geth first submit the transaction to mempool which is then pick by random miners which validate transaction. Is there a way I can bypass this process?

Comment: That wouldnt be a blockchain, you are removing the decentralized aspect of it, your are in need of a database, or maybe your questions needs more details.

Comment: Yes, you could write your own client, or modify an existing one. The problem isn't software but the competition with other miners.